# Ansible vmware_guest cannot ssh into vmware vSphere vCenter

Tags: ssh, ansible, vmware, vsphere

I'm trying to setup a virtual machine with ansible. However, ansible keeps getting stuck on the Deploy guest from template task.

Using -vvv, I got the following logs.

When attempting to log in via ssh pubkey auth:

```
TASK [Deploy guest from template]
```

---

```
task path: /home/wilb/Development/vcenter_demo/vcenter_demo.yml:12
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/vmware/vmware_guest.py
<vcenter.mycompany.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<vcenter.mycompany.com> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto 
  -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no 
  -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey 
  -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=root -o ConnectTimeout=10 
  -o ControlPath=/home/wilb/.ansible/cp/982c3c15ab 
  vcenter.mycompany.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
```

When I try to use --ask-pass, it gets stuck here:

```
TASK [Deploy guest from template] *******************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/wilb/Development/vcenter_demo/vcenter_demo.yml:14
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/vmware/vmware_guest.py
<vcenter.mycompany.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<vcenter.mycompany.com> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -C 
  -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o User=root 
  -o ConnectTimeout=10 
  -o ControlPath=/home/wilb/.ansible/cp/982c3c15ab 
  vcenter.mycompany.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
```

I can login to the vCenter manually. However, to access the shell, I first have to type: "shell" in the vCenter; by default it's some weird customized prompt.

How can I get ansible to log into vcenter properly to automatically deploy a VM?

**System**

- Controller OS: Fedora 26
- Ansible: 2.4.1
- vCenter: 6.5.0.1000

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww it's about the development of ansible scripts. There's an ansible tag on StackOverflow as well as an ssh and vsphere tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ansible vmware_guest cannot ssh into vmware vSphere vCenter

It should not.

You should call most of "cloud" modules from local machine.
Take a look at examples of [vmware_guest](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/vmware_guest_module.html): there's `delegate_to: localhost` everywhere.